# Cannot login with local or AD account after in-place upgrade of Windows 10

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, user-accounts

I've just performed an in-place upgrade of Windows 10 (1709) on a Windows 7 machine via ISO file on an USB. After the upgrade and a few reboots, I was greeted with a login screen for one of the local users (let's call this user OPL).

Windows asks me for my emailaddress/phone number and a password, however. I tried to log on to Windows as the local administrator, but this doesn't work. Whatever local account I try (there were several local accounts on this computer), none of them work and they all give me the same error:
"This password is incorrect. Check if you are using the password for your Microsoft-account. You can always reset your password on account.live.com/password/reset".
I've tried using AD accounts, but they give me the same error.

How can I enable the local accounts and our AD accounts again on this computer?

Comment: I’m confused. You say you (re-)installed Windows. How could there be any accounts on this system but the one you set up during the OOBE wizard? Or did you perhaps perform an upgrade?

Comment: @DanielB Sorry, I meant an in-place upgrade instead of an installation. I'll edit my question.

Comment: Why not try using an Ubuntu live disc to reset the passwords using a backdoor?

Comment: @InterLinked Why would the password of the local accounts have changed during the upgrade? If I try any of the local accounts, I always get the message that I need to reset my password on account.live.com (which is illogical for local accounts imho).

Comment: @InterLinked I opened a command prompt at the login screen, and listed all users with net user. Only guest and local administrator remain (the other have been wiped apparently). I changed the password for the local administrator, but when I try to log in (administrator or .\administrator), I get the same error message (go to account.live.com). Strange thing: when I boot the PC, I'm asked to log in as user OPL, but user OPL no longer is listed when I show net user.

Comment: @Joe Try creating a new administrative user. For example `net user newaccount mypassword` and then type `net localgroup administrators newacount /add` - as far as domain accounts, are you logging in in NetBIOS or FQDN form, e.g. MY_DOMAIN\user or user@mydomain.tld ?